# Typoscript get content by pidInList for Onepage-Layouted Site

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a onepage-layout and every page from the backend is a section of this frontend-page. Every section/backendpage has its own layout. The following script choose the correct layout:

```
20 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
      20 {
            file.cObject = CASE
            file.cObject {
                key.field = uid

                5 = TEXT
                5.value = fileadmin/template/green.html

                6 = TEXT
                6.value = fileadmin/template/blue.html

                default = TEXT
                default.value = fileadmin/template/default.html
            }
```

This works fine. Now I need the correct content in every section. I tried the following:

```
        variables {
                content < styles.content.get
                content{
                    select {
                        pidInList = 5
                        #pidInList = uid
                        where = colPos= 0 
                        #where = colPos={field: colPos}

                        orderBy = sorting
                    }
                }
            }
```

Setting pidInList to a static value like 5 works. But I need the correct content to the choosen layout-file. Why is uid not working?

Here is the complete block:

```
lib.sectionContent = HMENU
lib.sectionContent {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO = 1
    NO {
      doNotLinkIt = 1
      stdWrap >
      stdWrap {
        cObject = COA
        cObject {
          if.value = 5
          if.equals.field = doktype
          if.negate = 1
          10 < temp.titleSectionId
          10.wrap = <div id="|">


          20 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
          20 {
                file.cObject = CASE
                file.cObject {
                    key.field = uid

                    5 = TEXT
                    5.value = fileadmin/template/green.html

                    6 = TEXT
                    6.value = fileadmin/template/blue.html

                    default = TEXT
                    default.value = fileadmin/template/default.html
                }

                variables {
                    content < styles.content.get
                    content{
                        select {
                            pidInList.field = uid

                            where = colPos= 0 
                            #where = colPos={field: colPos}

                            orderBy = sorting
                        }
                    }
                }
          }
          30 = TEXT
          30 {
            wrap = </div>
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This one always choose the default value :-(

```
            variables {
                content < styles.content.get
                content{
                    select {
                        pidInList.cObject = CASE
                        pidInList.cObject {
                            key.field = uid

                            5 = TEXT
                            5.value = 5

                            default = TEXT
                            default.value = 10
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you use the uid in the template part:

```
key.field = uid
```

you need to specify the usage of the field uid for the content selection:

```
pidInList.field = uid
```

**BTW** in this way you have the templating hardcoded assigned to the pages.
Be aware of the fields `layout` and `backend_layout`, so an editor may select a layout for each page individually from a pool of templates.

Meanwhile I'm not sure about the possibility to select a field for pidInList directly.
but there is an alternative: **markers**
for selects you have the option to use and define markers for more readability.

```
select {
    pidInList = ###pageUid###
    #where  - already set by styles.content.get
    #orderBy - already set by styles.content.get
    markers {
      pageUid.field = uid
    }
  }
```

Comment: pidInList.field = uid is still not working. Now every section shows the content of the uid 1.

Comment: then you need to show your complete typoscript. I assumed that both parts are used in the same context.

Comment: I've added the complete block now. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I added another possible solution

Comment: Every section still shows the value of uid1. I've added another test in my question. This one always takes the default value. But why?

Comment: then your problem might lay deeper. can you debug the context of each page rendering: insert into the templates selected at 20.file.cObject a `<f:debug title="template 123">{_all}</f:debug>` and have a look at the `data` object which should be available.

Comment: Thats the way! The given content is correct. The problem seems to be in the template. I use this one for the output: <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.sectionContent.1.NO.stdWrap.cObject.20.variables.content" data="{colPos: 0}" />

Comment: One reason I do not like the excessive usage of `f:cObject` VH is the missing or unknown context. In this case even more worse as you use your variable definition in TS as the TS you try to evaluate with the cObject VH. If you want content in differnt columns define a variable for each column and use the appropiate variable in your template. You might have too much variables, but they most will be empty as there is no content in the page.